# How to remove double quotes from a string

Tags: php, string

This is my string:

```
$a='"some text';`
```

How can I remove the double quote so my output will look like this?

```
some text`
```

Comment: I have tried preg_replace but it didn't worked

Comment: @maget0ron: Do you use a cannon every time there's a mosquito in your bedroom, too?

Comment: @ Elias Van Ootegem-i thought it was better way to do .great one from you though Rofl:-)

Answer (score 44):

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo str_replace('"', '', $a);
```

Comment: This solution removes all the double quotes

Answer (score 22):

if string is: `$str = '"World"';`

`ltrim()` function will remove only first Double quote.

Output: `World"`

So instead of using both these function you should use `trim()`.
Example:

```
$str = '"World"';
echo trim($str, '"');
```

Output-

```
World
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Everyone who suggested str_replace -- that will replace *all* the double quotes. trim($str, '"') will remove double quotes from the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Probably makes the most sense to use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) since `str_replace()` will remove all the inner quote characters (depends, maybe that's what you want to happen).

> `ltrim` — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

```
echo ltrim($string, '"');
```

If you want to remove quotes from both sides, just use regular `trim()`, the second argument is a string that contains all the characters you want to trim.

Answer (score 2):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$a = str_replace('"', '', $a);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different functions are available for replacing characters from string below are some example

```
$a='"some text';
echo 'String Replace Function<br>';
echo 'O/P : ';
echo $rs =str_replace('"','',$a);
echo '<br>===================<br>';
echo 'Preg Replace Function<br>';
echo 'O/P : ';  
echo preg_replace('/"/','',$a);
echo '<br>===================<br>';
echo 'Left Trim Function<br>';
echo 'O/P : ';  
echo ltrim($a, '"');
echo '<br>===================';
```

Here is the output.

[image: Output image]

Comment: Please show the result as code instead of a screenshot, see why on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2257664).

Answer (score 1):

There have two ways you can remove double quotes also third brackets from an array string.

Sample 1:

```
$ids = ["1002","1006","1005","1003","1004"];
$string = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$ids);
$newString = preg_replace('/"/i', '', $string);
return $newString;
```

Sample 2:

```
function removeThirdBrackets($string)
 {
    $string = str_replace('[', '', $string);
    $string = str_replace(']', '', $string);
    $string = str_replace('"', '', $string);
    return $string;
 }
```

Output:

```
1002,1006,1005,1003,1004
```

Comment: After getting that output (those numbers separated by comma) `1002,1006,1005,1003,1004`, How do you insert them into an array?