# Get Only the value of field mongodb using laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-query-builder, laravel-facade

My question is similar with **[NodeJS get only value of MongoDB result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756899/nodejs-get-only-value-of-mongodb-result)**.
But in this case, i'm using laravel.

This is my controller :

```
public function validation(Request $request)
    {
        $email= $request->input('email');
        $password= $request->input('password');

        if (DB::table('customer')
            ->where('email','=',$email)
            ->where('password','=',$password)
            ->exists())
        {
            $data=DB::table('customer')
            ->select('first_name')
            ->where('email','=',$email)
            ->project(['_id' => 0])
            ->get();

            echo $data;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Wrong email or password';
        }
      }
```

And the output is :

```
[{"first_name":"John"}]
```

I want the result only 
   `John`         
 and removing field name, bracket, and the others.
What should i do ? And, is there any documentation for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out by myself. Based on [How to remove double quotes from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111887/how-to-remove-double-quotes-from-a-string).
The solution is using **trim** function.

Import this first on the controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

And then, got a little bit change on :

```
           $name=DB::table('customer')
            ->select('first_name')
            ->where('email','=',$email)
            ->project(['_id' => 0])
            ->get()
            ->flatten();

           $data=Str::of($name)->trim('[""]');
           echo $data;
```